# Сформировать запрос json x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: php, json

У меня есть url json вида `https://api.site.ru/api/feeds/office` переходя по которому я получаю 404 статус `{"statusCode":404,"message":"Cannot GET /api/feeds/office","error":"Not Found"}`. Также, у меня есть ключ для body. Если я в postman указываю в body ключ, то данные получаю.
А как на php сформировать Post запрос, чтобы получить данные json по этому url?

Comment: что такое "ключ для body"?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в документации указан ключ https://skrinshoter.ru/sO47usMjlAc
В postman  я его добавляю в body https://skrinshoter.ru/sO4bwhWq7vW

Comment: Ну, при курл запросах это обычный массив ключ значение (типа такого https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php#117009  и https://snipp.ru/php/curl#link-post-zapros) ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Как бы то ни было, этот запрос можно в постмане посмотреть (см. ответ)

Comment: ребята, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое, это в постмане нажать на кнопочку справа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и выбрать опцию формирования запроса в PHP:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: аххах. опередил )

Comment: спасибо большое!